# How to clear/overwrite all data in a shared memory?

Tags: multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.8

I need to overwrite all previously written data in a shared memory (multiprocessing.shared_memory).
Here is the sample code:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import json


shared = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=24, name='TEST')

data_one = {'ONE': 1, 'TWO': 2}
data_two = {'ACTIVE': 1}

_byte_data_one = bytes(json.dumps(data_one), encoding='ascii')
_byte_data_two = bytes(json.dumps(data_two), encoding='ascii')

# First write to shared memory
shared.buf[0:len(_byte_data_one)] = _byte_data_one
print(f'Data: {shared.buf.tobytes()}')

# Second write
shared.buf[0:len(_byte_data_two)] = _byte_data_two
print(f'Data: {shared.buf.tobytes()}')

shared.close()
shared.unlink()
```

#### Output:

First write: `b'{"ONE": 1, "TWO": 2}\x00\x00\x00\x00'`
Second write: `b'{"ACTIVE": 1}WO": 2}\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

The output is understandable, since the second write starts from index 0 and ends at `_byte_data_two` length. (`shared.buf[0:len(_byte_data_two)] = _byte_data_two`)

I need that every new write to shared memory to overwrite all previously data.

I've tried `shared.buf[0:] = b''` before every new write to shared memory but ended up getting 
`ValueError: memoryview assignment: lvalue and rvalue have different structures`
Also I've tried this `shared.buf[0:len(_bytes_data_two)] = b''` after every new write with the same result.

Looking after this result:
First write: `b'{"ONE": 1, "TWO": 2}\x00\x00\x00\x00'`
Second write: `b'{"ACTIVE": 1}\x00\x00\x00\x00'`  *without extra "**WO": 2}**" from first write*

How to overwrite all previously written data in a shared memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest might be to create a zero filled byte array first, something like:

```
def set_zero_filled(sm, data):
  buf = bytearray(sm.nbytes)
  buf[:len(data)] = data
  sm.buf[:] = buf
```

which you can use as:

```
set_zero_filled(shared, json.dumps(data_two).encode())
```